# Stop thread/object working using jcheckbox

Tags: java, multithreading

i have thread class

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardOwner;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;

public class BoardListener extends Thread implements ClipboardOwner {


    Clipboard sysClip = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Transferable trans = sysClip.getContents(this);
        regainOwnership(trans);
        System.out.println("Listening to board...");
        while(!isInterrupted()){
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void lostOwnership(Clipboard c, Transferable t) {
        try {
            this.sleep(50);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        }
        Transferable contents = sysClip.getContents(this);
        processContents(contents);
        regainOwnership(contents);
    }

    void processContents(Transferable t) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Processing: " + (String)t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    void regainOwnership(Transferable t) {
        sysClip.setContents(t, this);
    }
}
```

in main() i create object and object.start()

```
BoardListener b = new BoardListener(); 
b.start();
```

but i need somehow using jcheckbox stop/start working this object (stop clipboard monitoring).
Tried b.interupt(); doesn't work, tried setting flag in run while loop, doesn't help.

Comment: You might have a problem with "starvation", the loop in the run-method is very tight, might not let any other thread work for a long time.
Put som wait or sleep time in it to ensure the other code gets to execute.

Comment: How exactly did you try the flag setting? You could try it in processContents() - so it's still monitoring, but not printing. But the loop will run at regular intervals, perhaps a longer one when flag is false. Otherwise, depending on the app, it may be more efficient to just kill the thread. When needed again, instantiate and start a new thread.